# Does Israel have a record of fabricating evidence to exculpate itself from alleged crimes?

Tags: israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war

On 7 January 2024, journalist Hamza Al-Dahdouh, the son of Gaza-based Al Jazeera journalist Wael Al-Dahdouh, was killed in a missile strike on the car he was driving in by the IDF. This was the second of three separate Israeli attacks which killed members of the Al-Dahdouh family since the start of the war. There is [mounting concern](https://cpj.org/2024/01/journalist-casualties-in-the-israel-gaza-conflict/) regarding the unprecedented death toll of journalists in Gaza, and some reliable sources allege [[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1n_mq7mMNg), [2](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/rsf-says-killing-reuters-journalist-lebanon-targeted-strike-2023-10-29/)] that these strikes may be deliberate.

The IDF [initially claimed](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/idf-says-two-al-jazeera-journalists-were-killed-in-car-with-drone-operating-terror-operative/) that an occupant of the car was thought to be operating a drone which was viewed by the IDF as a potential threat. This was [rebutted](https://cpj.org/2024/01/cpj-calls-for-probe-into-whether-hamza-al-dahdouh-and-mustafa-thuraya-were-targeted-in-drone-strike/) by Al-Jazeera, which claimed that although one of the car occupants did use drones, this was in the context of journalistic work and not for military purposes, and furthermore that drones were not operated at the time the victims were driving. Several days later, the IDF [alleged](https://twitter.com/IDF/status/1745177413565223266) that two of the victims (including Hamza) were "terrorists", citing a document purportedly from Islamic Jihad, a Palestinian militant group currently engaged in hostilities with Israel.

Experts [cited by the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67946441) have disputed the authenticity of the document, citing among other things the "combination of English and Arabic text" which is unusual for Palestinian militant groups. The unusually poor quality of the document was also noted. [Al Jazeera flatly rejected](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/journalism-groups-family-reject-israeli-accusation-gazan-reporters-kil-rcna133666) and expressed outrage at the accusation, calling it a "false and misleading [attempt] to justify the killing of [their] colleague." At this time, there has been no independent verification of the document's authenticity.

Al Jazeera also made another provocative claim, one which is pertinent to this question. They claimed that "Israel has a well-known history of making false allegations and of fabricating evidence."

> Is this claim true? Are there proven instances in the past of Israel fabricating evidence or making false allegations? Are there other instances in this war where there is compelling evidence of Israel fabricating evidence?

While BBC and Al Jazeera's criticisms are interesting, it seems to me highly unusual for a Western government to completely fabricate evidence and publicly disseminate the fabricated evidence on social media, as Israel is alleged to have done. Although Western governments undoubtedly engage in deception on occasion, it is rarely something this blatant. For this reason, I *prima facie* find the allegation of fabrication unlikely. On the other hand, if there is an existing record of Israel engaging in such manipulation in the past, I would be significantly more inclined to change my stance.

Comment: This question largely focuses on some incidents that probably are quite disputed and on the other hand not very far reaching. The significance may be low. Should answers discuss these incidents then the question which is only in the title should be narrowed? Giving some examples of similar incidents might be okay (all may be too much for the typical length of an answer) but then the question should be more neutral. Something along the lines of "Did Israel in the past ....". Also, as it's formulated this question asks for yes/no which can typically be replaced by asking for the subject instead.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The answer is yes. I have uncovered one compelling example. I will update this answer in the future if I encounter further examples.

In 2018, Israel killed Gazan medic Rouzan al-Najjar during the 2018 Gazan March of Return, and subsequently engaged in a manipulation campaign to cover up their culpability.

Quoting Wikipedia:

> After initially reporting that an internal review showed that al-Najjar was not intentionally targeted, the IDF released video that purportedly showed al-Najjar admitting to being a human shield, with an IDF spokesman saying "Razan al-Najjar is not the angel of mercy Hamas propaganda is making her out to be."[20] The video that was released misleadingly took a prior interview that al-Najjar gave to a Lebanese television station out of context. She had said "I'm here on the line being a protective human shield saving the injured" and added she was at the protests to "save the wounded at the front lines", however the IDF released video cut out everything past "human shield".[6] The Israeli military was widely criticized for its efforts in manipulating the video, with commentators drawing parallels to past instances of the IDF manipulating or otherwise faking evidence.[6][7] A spokesman for the Israeli Prime Minister denied that editing the video was "political manipulation". The edited video was also shared by the Israeli ambassador to the United Kingdom and the Israeli Ministry of Foreign Affairs.[7] The Israeli ambassador to London, Mark Regev, in a tweet placed the description of her as "medical personnel" in quotation marks and continued that her death was further proof of Hamas' brutality.[21]

Comment: Can one example really be considered "a record"?

Answer (score 4):

> Does Israel have a record of fabricating evidence to exculpate itself from alleged crimes?

The main problem is that this is an example of the [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias): the question cannot be answered negatively, as such an answer would require providing [*evidence of absence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_absence) - even if somebody with extensive knowledge of this conflict asserts that Israel has never fabricated evidence, a new evidence may come to light afterwards or the existing facts can be disputed, depending on the sources one uses (which might be very pro- or anti-Israeli - see, e.g., [Al-Jazeera coverage](https://www.aljazeera.com/gallery/2023/11/9/the-war-on-gaza-a-masterclass-in-disinformation).)

So one has to gauge one's answer by saying something like *No, generally, Israel is not known for fabricating evidence*, or at least, has [less obvious record on the issue than the opposite side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pallywood). However lately, as [Israel struggles to justify its actions in Gaza, some imprecise claims have been made, which undermine Israel's credibility](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/information-missteps-led-questions-israels-credibility-rcna125723):

> And while some of Hamas’ propaganda has been able to sidestep Western efforts to limit its reach, Hellyer, whose career has included senior anti-radicalization roles in the U.K. government, said **this information war should not be seen as one between two equal parties.**
>
> **“We don’t take seriously what a terror group says, but we do take seriously what an army says**, especially one that’s an ally of ours,” he said. “So **we naturally hold it to a higher standard**.”

This falls in line with what the OP notes:

> [...]  it seems to me highly unusual for a Western government to completely fabricate evidence and publicly disseminate the fabricated evidence on social media, as Israel is alleged to have done.

Wikipedia article [*Media coverage of the Arab–Israeli conflict*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_coverage_of_the_Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_conflict) lists some [contentious incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_coverage_of_the_Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_conflict#Contentious_incidents), in many of which Israel was blamed and even accepted its guilt (like in [killing of Muhammad Al-Durrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_of_Muhammad_al-Durrah)), but later was either shown to be innocent or left off the hook for the lack of evidence.

Again, Al-Jazeera makes the completely opposite claims:

> In a statement to NBC News, the Al Jazeera Media Network said it “strongly condemns and wholly rejects — and indeed expresses its very considerable surprise at — the Israeli army’s false and misleading attempts to justify the killing of our colleague Hamza Wael Al-Dahdouh and other journalists,” the statement said.
>
> The statement added that **“Israel has a well-known history of making false allegations and of fabricating evidence”** and called for the international community to hold the IDF accountable.

*Rachel Corrie killing*
Worth mentioning [Rachel Corrie, an American activist who was killed by a bulldozer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Corrie#Death_and_subsequent_controversy), while trying to prevent demolition of Palestinian houses. There is some controversy on whether she was killed deliberately or accidentally.

See also:
[Misinformation in the 2023 Israel–Hamas war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misinformation_in_the_2023_Israel%E2%80%93Hamas_war)
[Balen report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balen_Report)